# refresh onCreateOptionMenu android

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I want to refresh the option menu each time it is called,

I have a functionality in which when the user clicks the option(add/remove favourite) in option menu, it checks whether it is favourite or not and do the functionality,

Problem : Once it creates the menu , it does not refresh the onCreateOptionMenu on 2nd time user presses the option button. I want to refresh the optionMenu each time it is pressed. Here is my code for this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (is_favorite.equals("1")) {
        menu.add(1, 22 ,0,"Remove from Favourites").setIcon(R.drawable.favorites_unselected);

    }
    else{
        menu.add(1, 11 ,0,"Add to Favourites").setIcon(R.drawable.favorites_selected);
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
  {

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {


    case 11:            
            //addtofavouritestask
            is_favorite = "1";

        return true;
    case 22:
        //removeFromFavouritestask
            is_favorite = "0";

        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `invalidateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: @Eric I am working on gingerbread, this method is for higher APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc, `onCreateOptionMenu (Menu menu)` is called **only once time**, so it does not refresh your menu. You must call the method `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` to refresh it (" **To update the menu every time it is displayed**, see `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)`").

So this should work :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (is_favorite.equals("1")) {
        menu.add(1, 22 ,0,"Remove from Favourites").setIcon(R.drawable.favorites_unselected);

    }
    else{
        menu.add(1, 11 ,0,"Add to Favourites").setIcon(R.drawable.favorites_selected);
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
  { 
menu.removeGroup(1);
if (is_favorite.equals("1")) {
        menu.add(1, 22 ,0,"Remove from Favourites").setIcon(R.drawable.favorites_unselected);

    }
    else{
        menu.add(1, 11 ,0,"Add to Favourites").setIcon(R.drawable.favorites_selected);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

Comment: hahahaha i also just did this, but removed the menu with groupID in onprepare, so it creates the desired option everytime